# Questions regarding phpMyAdmin Table Relations and DB Structure

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a website for use by a Youth Organisation to organize events, by providing a place for upcoming events to be listed and to be signed up to by members. In my database I have a table full of tags that can be assigned to events, quite like this website where you can tag your questions. I have another table to store the information about the events, for example title, description, requirements, date, etc.

I want to connect these databases up, so that when an event is made they are assigned a primary tag and an infinite amount of secondary tags from those in the tag table. Currently, I have a linking table that has a field for the event ID, the tag ID and whether the tag is the primary tag or not, however as I have had to set the fields to unique to allow me to create a relation I cannot store enter multiple event or tag IDs.

My question is, what is the the best way for me to structure my database for the functionality described above? Further more, if what I am doing correctly is correct, then how can I link the tables without either field in the linking table being a primary or unique key?

**tblEvents**
[image]

**tblTags**
[image]

Comment: you need an intermediate table for assignment that litterally takes the id of the event and the id of the tag. Table would be 3 columns - tableid, eventid, tagid

Comment: @Takarii Yeh, that's what I was assuming it would be, but without the tableid field and instead a field to say if the tag is assigned as a primary tag or secondary Thanks. However, please could you shed some light on the second point about how I assign the fields as foreign keys without making them unique or primary?

Comment: Put all the tags in the same table, then flag them as primary or secondary. Handle the limitation of 1 primary tag per event in your code outside of the database

Comment: @Takarii the tags can be either for primary or secondary. For example using the scenario of this website, this question is primarily SQL, so I would choose SQL as the primary tag, however it could also relate to PHP, which would therefore would be a secondary tag. Though on another question, it could be more about PHP, so that would be the primary and SQL would be the secondary. As a result, the primary or secondary defining needs to be stored separate from the tags table, so each assignment of the tag is defined as primary or secondary, rather than the tag itself. How can this be done?

Comment: Right, i see what you mean. In that case, do it in the assignment table as you are "assigning" that tag to be the primary - see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have whats referred to as a "many to many" relationship (many events can have many tags) you need an intermediate table that handles assignment - this is called normalisation.

In this case, you need 3 columns: AssignmentID, EventID, TagID

Put all your tags in the same database table, but flag each one as either primary or secondary and handle the 1 primary tag per event within your code outside of the database.

For example your tag table could look like:

```
ETagID  ETagName  ETagColour  ETagPrimary  ETagDel
1       first     red         1            0
2       second    blue        0            0
3       third     green       0            0
4       forth     yellow      1            0
5       fifth     orange      0            0
6       sixth     white       0            0
```

and your assignment table:

```
AssignmentID  EventID  TagID
1             1        1     
2             1        2
3             1        5
4             2        4
5             3        4
6             3        1
7             4        4
```

As your code outside of the sql handles the insertions in the first place, you can now query your tables using joins to pull out the event + tags for that event

```
SELECT ETagName, ETagColour FROM TagTable
JOIN AssignmentTable on AssignmentTable.TagID = TagTable.ETagID
JOIN EventTable on EventTable.EID = AssignmentTable.EventID
WHERE EventTable.EID = <some value> AND TagTable.ETagDel = 1
```

This would select all the tag names and colours for that specific event that aren't deleted.

An important thing to note is not to overcomplicate things. If your primary and secondary tags store the same info except for being either primary or secondary, then its pointless separating them into individual tables. Flagging them like I mentioned will be sufficient and reduces the number of tables required.

Hopefully this points you in the right direction moving forwards

**Update:**

As per the recent comment, you can handle the allocation of the primary tag within the assignment table. Create the same table as above, but include the primary flag column too

```
AssignmentID  EventID  TagID  PrimaryFlag
1             1        1      1  
2             1        2      0
3             1        5      0
4             2        4      1
5             3        4      1
6             3        1      0
7             4        4      1
```

then within the query, you can also select the status of the tag using a slightly modified version of the one written before:

```
SELECT ETagName, ETagColour, AssignmentTable.PrimaryFlag FROM TagTable
JOIN AssignmentTable on AssignmentTable.TagID = TagTable.ETagID
JOIN EventTable on EventTable.EID = AssignmentTable.EventID
WHERE EventTable.EID = <some value> AND TagTable.ETagDel = 1
```

if you want to make sure the primary tag appears at the top of that list, you can also bolt on

```
ORDER BY AssignmentTable.PrimaryFlag
```

Comment: I've tried to modify the SQL to collect all the information about the event and the information about it's primary tag, like so `SELECT EID, ETitle, EDesc, EReq, EStartD, EEndD, ESUDeadline, EMaleS, EMaleTS, EFemaleS, EFemaleTS, tblTags.ETagColour FROM tblEvents
JOIN tblTagLink on tblTagLink.ETagID = tblTags.ETagID
JOIN tblEvents on tblEvents.EID = tblTagLink.EventID
WHERE tblEvents.EID = 1 AND tblTagsLink.ETagPrime = 1`. However I get the error `#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'tblEvents'`. Any suggestioon? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ThomasSmyth you are trying to join a table that isnt needed. You are selecting from tblEvents, so you don't need the join

Comment: I want to collect the information for the event and the information of the primary tag for that event. Surely, I have to join the tables to reference the tblTags for the data of the primary tag? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @ThomasSmyth The error is being generated because the table `tblEvents` is already referenced as your `FROM`.  When the database talks of an error 1066, it is suggesting that you have used the same reference twice (either the table name directly, or an already used alias). From what you posted, i can see what you are attempting to do, however all you are doing is creating a circular join. In order to get the details of the primary tag, use the query i posted above but add any additional details you want to select into the select part of the statement - that will get your details

Comment: I've modified your statement as little as possible: `SELECT ETagName, ETagColour, tblTagLink.ETagPrime FROM tblTagLink
JOIN tblTagLink on tblTagLink.ETagID = tblETags.ETagID
JOIN tblEvents on tblEvents.EID = tblTagLink.EID
WHERE tblEvents.EID = 1 AND tblETags.ETagDel = 1`, however still get the same error.

Comment: @ThomasSmyth you seem to have just moved the problem to another table. you cant do `FROM tblTagLink` AND `JOIN tblTagLink` - its entirely unneeded.

Comment: Silly me. I just got what you mean. Thanks!